How do I replace the default SuspenseFallback for a route in Expo Router?
I'm using Expo Router in my React Native project and want to customize default Suspense fallback behavior for all routes. By default, Expo Router shows a loading spinner when a route is being loaded asynchronously (in dev mode - nothing in prod), but I want to replace it with a custom fallback UI, such as a custom loading screen or a skeleton loader.
Here's an example of how my route looks in Expo Router:
// app/_layout.tsx

import "expo-dev-client";
import { StrictMode, Suspense } from "react";

import { QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { Slot } from "expo-router";

import { LoadingFullScreen } from "components/LoadingFullScreen";
import { queryClient } from "constants/queryClient";

export default function Root() {
  return (
    <StrictMode>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingFullScreen />}>
          <Slot />
        </Suspense>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </StrictMode>
  );
}

app/asyncPage.tsx

import { useSuspenseQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

import { PageView } from "components/PageView";

export default function AsyncPage() {
  const { data } = useSuspenseQuery({
    queryKey: ["loading"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      return "loaded";
    },
  });

  return (
    <PageView>
      <View>
        <Text>{data}</Text>
      </View>
    </PageView>
  );
}

Chasing this through the suspense tree in dev tools, it looks like each route has it's own Suspense component injected by Expo Router, which means the Suspense I am defining in _layout.tsx never get's invoked, as it's higher up the tree.

Is there anyway to override this at the top level, or would it need to be done for each route?
